# UITableView simple question?

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, uitableview

I have an UITableView on one of my views,so the problem is when the users select a row of the table,the row becomes blue and a view is pushed by an UINavigationController,when i back to the main view the row still with a blue background.How can i make the row look normal,with no background color?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can deselect the row, best is to do it when you push the next view:

[tableView deselectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:NO];

Comment: can you be more specific,please!

Comment: The above line put in your didSelectRowAtIndexPath-method will make the row look normal again.